# Discover multiple jwplayers on a page

Tags: jwplayer

I need to write some javascript code which will loop through all jwplayers available on a page.

The jwplayer api has a function selectPlayer():

```
var player = jwplayer.api.selectPlayer();
```

But this only returns the first player on the page. I can't see a way to find them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but the simplest would be to call "jwplayer(*x*)" - **where *x* is a zero-based index relating to an Array of jwplayers on the page** - as this will return the Player instance at that index.

So for JW7 / JW8 you could simply do the following:

```
var jwpAll = document.querySelectorAll('.jwplayer');
for(var jwpIndex=0,jwpTotal=jwpAll.length;jwpIndex<jwpTotal;jwpIndex++){
    var player = jwplayer(jwpIndex);
}
```

Comment: I came to this same conclusion in the meantime but seeing as I didn't get round to answering my own question will accept yours :)