# Tracking multiple jwplayer divs

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I'm pretty confused over this.
I have two divs where jw player is initialized

```
<div id="player"></div>
<div id="player1"></div>
<script>
    jwplayer("player").setup({
        file: "https://player.vimeo.com/external/135492851.hd.mp4?s=a61836463fbde188aaa1e24e6bfeeb39&profile_id=113",
        startparam: "starttime",
    });

    jwplayer("player1").setup({
        file: "https://player.vimeo.com/external/135492851.hd.mp4?s=a61836463fbde188aaa1e24e6bfeeb39&profile_id=113",
        startparam: "starttime",
    });
</script>
```

The jwplayer object is initialized.
But, when I run `jwplayer().getContainer();`, It only returns only the first div, that is `player`. This is the returned value.
`<div id="player" class="jwplayer jw-reset jw-state-idle jw-skin-five jw-stretch-....`

Since only first div is called, I am not able to track the activities of the second div.
What am I doing wrong? Please guide

**EDIT**

I want to see on what all divs is jwplayer initialized, and I want to track those divs separately. There is an option to do `jwplayer("player").getContainer();` but I'll have to specify the divs, which won't be possible if I had to think of a scalable solution in mind.

The approach I had in mind, identify the divs which have a jwplayer content. Parse all those divs using a loop, and raise jwplayer events based on each div. Is this the right approach?

Comment: jwplayer().getContainer()[1];

Comment: no, it doesn't work, it shows `undefined`

Comment: jwplayer("player").getContainer() - for the first instance; jwplayer("player1").getContainer() - for the second instance;

Comment: @jherrieven Yes, that is possible, but it won't be a scalable solution. I have updated the question, please have a look. Thanks :)

Comment: The following answer might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733833/discover-multiple-jwplayers-on-a-page/46769982#46769982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had a similar use case. I'll just share my approach in case it helps you.

1. Looped through all the divs present on the page.
2. Now, since the jw player divs have an id associated to it.
3. Check those ids and make a collection of them.
4. Use the div ids available to populate the jwplayer containers.
5. You should now be able to track all those player instances.

Comment: looping through all the divs, would this have a performance overhead?

Comment: i don't think it should have any. plus it actually depends on how you have implemented the whole dom structure